# Is it compulsory to have facebook app installed to show facebook ads

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-audience-network

Is it necessary that the user of my app must have facebook application installed for ads to appear on my application.

Answer (score 0):

Our experience has been that the user needs to have used the Facebook app to login within the past 30(?) days for FAN ads to appear.